# add day to date in title fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, slide

I have a pageview with fragments.

Those fragments are added to the adapter that is managing the pageview by the slide movement on the screen. Each time the user slides do the left and he is on the last fragment, on new fragment is created and added to the adapter/pageview.

The thing is, I want the title of each fragment to be the day of the week and the day, like a calendar. The problem is, when I get into the last day of that week, I get two fragment with the same title:

[image]
My code:

`Date date = new Date();`//before my onCreate method

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager myViewPager) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE - d MMM");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);

        if(adapter.getCount() % 7 == 0){
            date = calendar.getTime();
            String day = sdf.format(date);
            adapter.addFragment(new Diafragment(), day);
        }
        else if (adapter.getCount() % 7 == 1){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            date = calendar.getTime();
            String dayplusone = sdf.format(date);
            adapter.addFragment(new Diafragment(), dayplusone);
        }
        else if (adapter.getCount() % 7 == 2){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            date = calendar.getTime();
            String dayplustwo = sdf.format(date);
            adapter.addFragment(new Diafragment(), dayplustwo);
        }
        else if (adapter.getCount() % 7 == 3){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            date = calendar.getTime();
            String dayplustree = sdf.format(date);
            adapter.addFragment(new Diafragment(), dayplustree);
        }
        else if (adapter.getCount() % 7 == 4){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            date = calendar.getTime();
            String dayplusfour = sdf.format(date);
            adapter.addFragment(new Diafragment(), dayplusfour);
        }
        else if (adapter.getCount() % 7 == 5){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            date = calendar.getTime();
            String dayplusfive = sdf.format(date);
            adapter.addFragment(new Diafragment(), dayplusfive);
        }
        else if (adapter.getCount() % 7 == 6){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            date = calendar.getTime();
            String dayplussix = sdf.format(date);
            adapter.addFragment(new Diafragment(), dayplussix);
        }

        myViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myViewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount());
    }

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragments.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitles.add(title);
}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have much to do with the title... And I think you should do a simple loop instead of a wall of if/else if

Comment: Just compare with today date, and prevent user from sliding if it reach today ?

Comment: @NicolasMaltais how so ? I do the if/else so I can get the string to use in the Title, right ?

Comment: @Jacky it will happen from time to time, 1st time is after 6 days I think, then 5 days and so on